# IOS, How to set Auto Layout in your UITableViewCell that contains different Subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a layout issue, i have a UIView that contains an UIImageView and three other UILabels. The part that needs to set the layout dynamically is the main UIView thats added to the cell and a UILabel that will contain text of any length lets say for this example.

What i have done i created a custom UITableViewCell and added the SubViews to the custom UITableViewCell, like here:

```
        -(void)setupView:(PostInfo*)postInfo{


            CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            viewPostMessage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, screenRect.size.width - 20, 100)];
            viewPostMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:193.0f/255 green:193.0f/255 blue:193.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            viewPostMessage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            viewPostMessage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;


            if(postInfo.userImage.length > 0){
            userImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
            UIImage *imageUser =  [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.hugt.co.uk/userimage/%d/userImage.jpg", postInfo.userId]]]];
            userImage.image = imageUser;
            [viewPostMessage addSubview:userImage];
            }else{
            UIView *viewImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
            viewImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:132.0f/255 green:132.0f/255 blue:132.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            [viewPostMessage addSubview:viewImage];

            userImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)];
            UIImage *imageUser = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultuser.jpg"];
            userImage.image = imageUser;
            [viewImage addSubview:userImage];
            }

            labelUserName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 8, 200, 16)];
            labelUserName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:56.0f/255 green:56.0f/255 blue:57.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            labelUserName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ posted...", postInfo.firstName,postInfo.lastName];
            //labelFirstName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            labelUserName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
            labelUserName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [viewPostMessage addSubview:labelUserName];

            labelCreated = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 24, 200, 16)];
            labelCreated.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:86.0f/255 green:152.0f/255 blue:179.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            labelCreated.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:postInfo.timeStampCreated dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            labelCreated.text = [labelCreated.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@""];
            labelCreated.text = [labelCreated.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@""];
            //labelFirstName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            labelCreated.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
            labelCreated.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [viewPostMessage addSubview:labelCreated];

            labelMessage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 43, 210, 50)];
            labelMessage.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141.0f/255 green:142.0f/255 blue:142.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            labelMessage.text = postInfo.message;
            labelMessage.numberOfLines = 3;
            //labelFirstName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            labelMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
            labelMessage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [labelMessage sizeToFit];
            [viewPostMessage addSubview:labelMessage];

            [self.contentView addSubview:viewPostMessage];

        }
```

When i create this custom UITableViewCell i pass in an object that sets the text on the UILabels, like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";


            if(tableViewThreads == tableView){
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }
            ThreadInfo *threadInfo = (ThreadInfo*)[self.threadsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self setupThreadItem:threadInfo]];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            return cell;

            }
            if(tableViewPosts == tableView){
            PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }

            PostInfo *postInfo = (PostInfo*)[self.postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell setupView:postInfo];



            //[cell addSubview:[self setupPostItem:postInfo]];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            return cell;
            //[cell.contentView addSubview:[self setupThreadItem:threadInfo]];
            }

            return nil;
        }
```

I have searched the web and also here to find out how to Auto Layout the Subviews in the cell but can't seem to understand what needs to go next. I read that you need a Prototype Cell so i created a custom UITableViewCell and thats how far I've got.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So far i have got the cells to resize with Auto Layout but i have removed the UIView that sits inside the cell, so now i have three UILabels and an UIImageView which are the UIImageView (userImage), UILabel (labelUsername), UILabel (labelCreated) and UILabel (labelMessage). So the dimensions and coordinates are the same just that the UIView has been removed:

First i set up NSLayoutContsraints in my Custom Cell, code bellow:

Set numberOFLines = 0 and remove sizeToFit on the UILabel thats going to AutoLayout.

```
-(void)setupView:(PostInfo*)postInfo{


            CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            viewPostMessage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, screenRect.size.width - 20, 100)];
            viewPostMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:193.0f/255 green:193.0f/255 blue:193.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            viewPostMessage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            viewPostMessage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;


            if(postInfo.userImage.length > 0){
            userImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
            UIImage *imageUser =  [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.hugt.co.uk/userimage/%d/userImage.jpg", postInfo.userId]]]];
            userImage.image = imageUser;
            [self.contentView addSubview:userImage];
            }else{
            UIView *viewImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
            viewImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:132.0f/255 green:132.0f/255 blue:132.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            [self.contentView addSubview:viewImage];

            userImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)];
            UIImage *imageUser = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultuser.jpg"];
            userImage.image = imageUser;
            [viewImage addSubview:userImage];
            }

            labelUserName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 8, 200, 16)];
            labelUserName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:56.0f/255 green:56.0f/255 blue:57.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            labelUserName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ posted...", postInfo.firstName,postInfo.lastName];
            //labelFirstName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            labelUserName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
            labelUserName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [self.contentView addSubview:labelUserName];

            labelCreated = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 24, 200, 16)];
            labelCreated.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:86.0f/255 green:152.0f/255 blue:179.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            labelCreated.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:postInfo.timeStampCreated dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            labelCreated.text = [labelCreated.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@""];
            labelCreated.text = [labelCreated.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@""];
            //labelFirstName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            labelCreated.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
            labelCreated.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [self.contentView addSubview:labelCreated];

            labelMessage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 43, 210, 50)];
            labelMessage.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141.0f/255 green:142.0f/255 blue:142.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
            labelMessage.text = postInfo.message;
            labelMessage.numberOfLines = 0;
            //labelFirstName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            labelMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
            labelMessage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            labelMessage.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            //[labelMessage sizeToFit];
            [self.contentView addSubview:labelMessage];

            labelMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

            [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[bodyLabel]-19-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"bodyLabel": labelMessage }]];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-43-[bodyLabel]-6-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"bodyLabel": labelMessage }]];

            //[self.contentView addSubview:viewPostMessage];

        }
```

Then in my ViewController that contains the UITableVIew, i modified this bit of code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
            if(tableViewThreads == tableView){

            return 122;

            }
            if(tableViewPosts == tableView){
            PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }

            PostInfo *postInfo = (PostInfo*)[self.postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell setupView:postInfo];

            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];

            CGFloat h = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

            return h + 1;


            }
            return 0;
        }
```

**The Cells do now resize and the UILabel resizes automatically now but my other problem is that the UITableView scroll is not smooth so ill have to fix that, and when i scroll in the UITableView the Cell data from the UILabel (labelMessage) seems to print it self in other cells, don't know why this is**

BUT the Cells resize and the other issues ill ask another question on here.

Sorry forgot to add this bit of code that sits in the PostTableViewCell:

```
        - (void)layoutSubviews
        {
            [super layoutSubviews];

            // Make sure the contentView does a layout pass here so that its subviews have their frames set, which we
            // need to use to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth below.
            [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

            // Set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the mutli-line bodyLabel based on the evaluated width of the label's frame,
            // as this will allow the text to wrap correctly, and as a result allow the label to take on the correct height.
            labelMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(labelMessage.frame);
        }
```

Comment: one big problem I see is using `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:`. Unless you know those images are cached that's a blocking(synchronous) call to the network that should never be executed on the main thread (which I'm assuming your -setupView: is running on.)

Comment: So I would have to use dispatch queue

Comment: Yeah that would be one way to load the image. but then you need to switch back to the main queue to actually set the UIImage on the UIImageView. You could also use [AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.4.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html). It has a sweet category on UIImageView for loading/setting the image asynchronously.